# Matlab xstrich variable not appearing in workspace?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

The xstrich is not appearing in workspace. Can you advice how can I fix it?

```
v=1;
for k = 3527:3671
   jpgFilename = strcat('gray','_',num2str(k),'.jpg');
   if exist(jpgFilename,'file')
     imageData = imread(jpgFilename);
     data = imageData(:,:,2);
     image = imageData(:)';%'//
     xstrich(v) = [xstrich;image];
    v=v+1;
   end
end
```

Comment: Does any of your files exist (what is the final value of `v`?)? Are you running this inside a function?

Comment: I assume you put this inside a function, and then you have to assign it to the function output as well. If this code is not inside a function, `xstrich` is most likely empty and therefore not showing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously! 
While having a loop with decreasing order, the operation inside is never reached:

```
for k = 3527:3071
    % never reaches here
end
```

Either change the order or use `-1`.

```
for k = 3527:-1:3071
    % reaches here
end
```

**Update:**

After updating your question, now you should check if the condition of the `if-loop` is met. It means that,

1. the files exist
2. they are placed at a path that can be seen my MATLAB

Comment: Ahh, completely missed that:)

Comment: I have fixed it, but still xstrich is not appearing `
v = 1;
for k = 3527:3671
jpgFilename = strcat('gray','_',num2str(k),'.jpg');
if exist(jpgFilename,'file')
imageData = imread(jpgFilename);
imshow(imageData);
data = imageData(:,:,2);
image = imageData(:)';
xstrich(v) = [xstrich;image];
v = v+1;
end
end`

Comment: @user3450687 then you should check if the `if` condition is met.

Comment: I have made so stupid mistakes. Thank you so much :)